# Copy a PDF documents with unique, numbered watermarks

Tags: javascript, pdf, acrobat

I need to create a number of copies of a PDF document and place a unique identifier on each copy.  How can I do this?

I posted this question so that I could share my working solution using JavaScript in Adobe Acrobat(see answer below) but feel free to post alternatives.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote the Acrobat JavaScript below to create copies of a PDF document, each with a unique watermark.  It is tested in Acrobat X Pro but presumably works in other versions.

The script itself includes comments about how to use it in Acrobat.  In short, make sure JavaScript is enabled in Preferences, open the JavaScript Console (CTRL + J), paste the code, select it and hit CTRL + ENTER to run it.

The script first prompts the user to enter a commas separated list of values.  For example:

```
COPY 01,COPY 02,COPY 03
```

The user is then prompted to select a PDF document.  Then the script takes over.  For each comma separated value entered it creates a copy of the PDF document with that value (in the same folder as the original) and adds that value as a watermark on every page of the document.

Using the example commas separated list above, the first file copy would be named "Report COPY 01.pdf" and would contain the watermark "COPY 01" on every page.

**Variables to Change Settings**

`iWatermarkFont` - name of font (default is "Arial")
`iWatermarkFontSize` - sets font size; whole number between 0 and 72
`iWatermarkOpacity` - sets the opacity (transparency) of the watermark; decimal from 0 (invisible) to 1 (standard text)
`iWatermarkRotation` - rotation angle, typically 45, -45 or 0
`baseFileName` - used as the prefix for PDF copies created

**Adobe Acrobat JavaScript (includes notes on how to use it)**

```
// ————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————
// ————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————
// ————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————
//
//      C R E A T E    C O P I E S   O F   A   P D F   W I T H   U N I Q U E   W A T E R M A R K S
//
//
//     This script prompts the user to select a PDF
//     file and makes copies of the file, each with a
//     unique watermark.  The script prompts the user
//     to enter a list of watermark values separated by
//     commas.
//      
//     Up to 50 IDs can be set at a time in this variable.
//     Set the variable equal to text surrounded by
//     double quotes, with each item separated by a
//     comma.  The following example would create 3
//     copies with the watermarks:
//
//          "COPY 01,COPY 02,COPY 03"
//
// ————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————
// ————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————
// ————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————


// —————————————————————————————————————————————————————
// —————————————————————————————————————————————————————
//  HOW TO RUN JAVACRIPTS IN ACROBAT:
// —————————————————————————————————————————————————————
//
//      1) First turn on JavaScript in Acrobat.  Go to 
//          Edit > Preferences.  Select the "JavaScript" 
//          category.  Check the boxes for "Enable 
//          Acrobat JavaScript" and "Enable Interactive 
//          Console".
//
//      2) To open the JavaScript Debugger in Acrobat,
//          press CTRL + J.
//
//      3) In the main "Console" area of the JavaScript 
//          Debugger, paste the entire text of the 
//          script.  NOTE:  Make sure any existing text 
//          is cleared out first.
//
//      4) In the main "Console" area of the Javascript 
//          Debugger, press CTRL + A to select all of
//          the text you just pasted into the "Console".
//
//      5) Press CTRL + ENTER to run the script. 
//          Remember, it won't work unless all the text 
//          of the script (and only that text) is
//          selected.
// —————————————————————————————————————————————————————
// —————————————————————————————————————————————————————


// —————————————————————————————————————————————————————
// —————————————————————————————————————————————————————
//  GET USER INPUT
// —————————————————————————————————————————————————————
var csvListOfIDs = app.response({cQuestion:"Enter a list of text watermarks.  Separate each item with a comma.\n\n - Don't include spaces between commas.\n - The only special characters allowed are dashes and underscores.", cTitle:"Multiple Copies with Unique Watermarks", cDefault:"COPY 01, COPY 02, COPY 03, COPY 04, COPY 05", cLabel:"Watermarks"});


// —————————————————————————————————————————————————————
// —————————————————————————————————————————————————————
// USER VARIABLES
// —————————————————————————————————————————————————————

// Watermark Settings
var iWatermarkFont = "Arial";       // Name of a font to use in the watermark, for example, "Arial".
var iWatermarkFontSize = 64;
var iWatermarkOpacity = .10;        // Enter a decimal.  Default=.15    Transparent=0   Opaque=1
var iWatermarkRotation = 45;


// —————————————————————————————————————————————————————
// —————————————————————————————————————————————————————
//  CREATE NUMBERED, WATERMARKED COPIES
// —————————————————————————————————————————————————————

if (csvListOfIDs == null) {
    app.alert("Cancelled", 3);
} else {
    // Get an array of values from the CSV IDs and trim the
    //  excess whitespace.
    var str_array = csvListOfIDs.split(",");
    for(var i = 0; i < str_array.length; i++) {
       str_array[i] = str_array[i].replace(/^\s*/, "").replace(/\s*$/, "");
    };


    // Prompt the user to pick a file.
    var userPickedDoc = app.browseForDoc();


    // Validate the user selection.
    if (typeof userPickedDoc != "undefined") {
        // User picked a document.


        // Define the user picked document object.
        var myURL = (userPickedDoc.cFS=="CHTTP") ? encodeURI(userPickedDoc.cPath) : userPickedDoc.cPath;
        var sourceDoc = app.openDoc({cPath: myURL, cFS: userPickedDoc.cFS});


        // Get the folder where the user picked document is saved.
        var lastSlashPos = sourceDoc.path.lastIndexOf("/");
        var folderPath = sourceDoc.path.substr(0, lastSlashPos) + "/";


        // Define the base file name to use when saving output documents.
        var baseFileName = "Doc"
        // —————————————————————————————————————————————————————
        // —————————————————————————————————————————————————————


        // Create a temp copy of the original file to protect
        //  the original during the script.
        var tempInitialFileName = "COPY OF INITIAL FILE"


        // Save and close the COPY of the original file.
        sourceDoc.saveAs(folderPath + tempInitialFileName + ".pdf");
        sourceDoc.closeDoc(true);


        // Create Watermarked Copies
        for(var i = 0; i < str_array.length; i++) {

            // Open the unmodified temp copy of the original file.
            var iNewFile = app.openDoc(folderPath + tempInitialFileName + ".pdf");

            // Apply a watermark.
            iNewFile.addWatermarkFromText({
                cText: str_array[i],
                nTextAlign:app.constants.align.center,
                cFont: iWatermarkFont,
                nFontSize: iWatermarkFontSize,
                aColor: color.black,
                nOpacity: iWatermarkOpacity,
                nRotation: iWatermarkRotation
            });

            // Save the new document with a unique name using the ID.
            iNewFile.saveAs(folderPath + baseFileName + " " + str_array[i] + ".pdf");

            // Close the new document.
            iNewFile.closeDoc(true);
        };

    } else {
        // User cancelled file selection.
        app.alert("Cancelled", 3);
    }
}
```